# Expressing $P(X \vee Y | Z)$ without the disjunction operator

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm trying to express $P(X \vee Y | Z)$ without the disjunction operator. I have the following already, but I am not sure whether this is correct.

$P(X \vee Y | Z) = \frac{P\left(\left( X \vee Y \right) \wedge Z \right)}{P\left(Z\right)}$

This can then be rewritten to:

$P(X \vee Y | Z) = \frac{P\left(X \wedge Z \right) + P\left(Y \wedge Z \right) - P\left(X \wedge Y \wedge Z \right)}{P\left(Z\right)}$

So basically it boils down to:

$P(X \vee Y | Z) = P(X|Z)+P(Y|Z)-P(X\wedge Y|Z)$

Is this true or have I made a mistake somewhere?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\color{green}{\checkmark}$ Yes; you've got it.   The formula for PIE in conditional probability is directly analogous to the formula for PIE in unconditional probability.

Although we normally use set notation for event junctions rather than logic symbols.

`\cap` $\cap$, `\cup` $\cup$ rather than `\wedge` $\wedge$, `\vee` $\vee$

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(X \cup Y \mid Z) & = \frac{\mathsf P\left(\left( X \cup Y \right) \cap Z \right)}{\mathsf P\left(Z\right)}
\\[1ex]
 & = \frac{\mathsf P\left(X \cap Z \right) + \mathsf P\left(Y \cap Z \right) - \mathsf P\left(X \cap Y \cap Z \right)}{\mathsf P\left(Z\right)}
\\[1ex]
 & = \mathsf P(X\mid Z)+\mathsf P(Y\mid Z)-\mathsf P(X\cap Y\mid Z)
\end{align}$$

Thus demonstrating that Principle of Inclusion Exclusion operates over whatever $\sigma$-field we measure the probability.